# If the input field is blank, set a specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I'm designing a shopping cart system for my site. I have an input to enter the quantity for each item, with the value 1 automatically put in. The problem is, if someone clicks in the input and deletes the 1, leaving the field blank, then the item isn't added to the cart.

How can I set a 1 in the input field if it is blank, either using js or jquery? Or if the field is blank have the form automatically submit a 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$("#input_ID").blur(function() {
    if($.trim($(this).val()) === "") {
        $(this).val("1");
    }
});
```

If it needs to be a group of inputs, simply give them a common class and change:

```
$("#input_ID").blur( . . .
```

. . . to:

```
$(".class_name").blur( . . .
```

Comment: Note that you should use the `change` event, and you can use a callback to `val` instead of a clunky `if` statement: http://jsfiddle.net/f2v5J/

Comment: @Ian - what advantage do you see of using `change` over `blur`?

Comment: Oh, and the if was more for clarity's sake . . . make sure that the approach is readable to readers of different skill levels.   ;)

Comment: If the user doesn't make a change to the textbox value, why bother running the code and checking for this? `change` will only execute when the user leaves the textbox but actually made a change. `blur` will execute every time the user leaves the textbox

Comment: Fair enough . . . my main reason for doing it on `blur` is simply because I tend to use a standard "on blur" approach to field validation . . . since some input fields can trigger `change` without losing focus, using blur for all of them keeps the validation approach consistent.  `change` would certainly work fine in this case.

Comment: You're absolutely right that `blur` is fine, I just see it as an event that can occur too often for something like input validation. I have a question though - what do you mean by `since some input fields can trigger change without losing focus` - I don't know what you mean and I've never seen that happen before.

Comment: `<select>` elements are the most notorious for that.  If you set up a dropdown with an alert that shows on the change event, and then click on it and select a new value, the change event will fire, while the dropdown still has focus.

Comment: I see what you mean (just tested in a jsFiddle). I don't see how using an `alert` has any relation to this though; `change` fires immediately, even when the `<select>` doesn't lose focus. Anyways, if it even counts, it depends on how you look at it. While it doesn't follow the way other elements act (firing `change` after the element is blurred), it makes sense because you've selected an `<option>` and that's been blurred. It really all ends up being the developer's preference - when they want to validate the `<select>`; as soon as something is selected (how it's always done), or after blur

Comment: For the other input elements, it doesn't make sense to me to use blur (even `<select>` too)

Comment: It's all going to depend on the type of action that occurs on the input.  For example, one of the other answers (since removed) suggested clearing out the value in the textbox on `focus` (a popular approach for displaying help text or formatting guidance in a field when it is empty).  In a situation like that, if the the user doesn't enter a value when they leave the field, then there is no `change` event (the field was empty after the `onfocus` event fired and it is still empty when the user leaves).  'onblur` would be needed to change the value to `1` in that case.

Comment: As for `<selects>`, there are certainly cases where you want the user to see the result of a selection as the value changes (e.g., dynamically update the color of a product image based on a dropdown selection), but it is far more common to want to wait for the final choice before processing a `<select>` option.  For example, designs that redirect the user or load data with Ajax, based on a dropdown option. In both cases, you generally don't want to process the selection until the final selection is made, so that you aren't redirecting or loading data for accidental selections.

Comment: I guess it's just become a matter of preference/opinion. I've almost never seen a reason to "wait" for a user to be "done choosing". It's usually understand that choosing an option is their "final" choice. And anyways, outside of `<select>`, I don't see a reason to use `blur`

Comment: In the end, it all comes down to requirements.  :)  I run into all kinds of situations where clients request certain kinds of behaviors for their pages.  I try to guide the designs as best I can for the optimal user experience, but, in the end, they pay the bills, so I come up with the best/most efficient implementation that I can, based on what they want . . . even if it's not the way that I would have gone.   ;)

Comment: And, on a side note, if you've `almost never seen a reason to "wait" for a user to be "done choosing"`, I'm guessing that you don't have to deal with ADA requirements for dropdowns very often.   :D

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = $(your_input).val();
if ( value == '' ) value = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is only js no jquery.

Within your internal function, wherever you are saving the input.
For example:

```
let itemQuantity = document.getElementById("item_quantity");

//you can also add account for space or other non numeric values (consider looking into regex)

if (itemQuantity === ""){ 
itemQuantity = 1    
// or "1" depending on how you need to pass the values
return taskPriority;
}
```

alternate:

```
if (itemQuantity.value === ""){ 
itemQuantity = 1    
// or "1" depending on how you need to pass the values
}
```

The first one will force the user to reset default to 1 and then add to cart again.
Second will by default set it to 1 if they input blank values.

that should allow you to set a default value.